# Как разместить текст по центру?

Tags: html, css, позиционирование

У меня на сайте html есть текст, и я хочу чтобы он был по центру, как мне это сделать? Уже пытался найти варианты, но так и не вышло!..

Comment: То есть серьёзно, по запросу типа "css/html текст по центру" ничего не нашло? Слабо верится.

Comment: `text-align: center;` же, если блок по центру, то `margin: auto;`

Answer (score 2):

Тема действительно изъезжена на тысячах ресурсов, но раз тут ищут ответ:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

За выравнивание текста отвечает `text-align` со значением `center`.